# Open (toggle) div when scrolled

Tags: javascript, html

Just asking whats the code in toggling or opening a form/div when the user started scrolling the page. Just like the sign up form.

Comment: Can you post some code telling us what you tried?

Comment: Maybe somebody can give you an answer but you should take a look at this before you post your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really basic Javascript sample I whipped up: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EGC_SoftwareDev/17ho8t6p/6/)

```js
var divToOpen = document.getElementById('divToOpen');
divToOpen.style.display = 'none';

document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
 divToOpen.style.display = 'block';
}, true);
```

```css
#divToOpen {
  background-color: green;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Top</h1>
  <div id="divToOpen">
    <h2>I'm now open!</h2>
  </div>
  <div style="height:350px;">
  </div>
  <h1> Bottom</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem! Hopefully it gives you somewhere to start! Please mark this as accepted if it solves your issue :)